# Intraweb for iphone, how to keep the webbrowser hidden

Tags: iphone, delphi, delphi-2010, intraweb

I've just written my first app in intraweb (control pack for the iphone)
It works, but after several hours I still cannot get the iphone to **not** show safari.

I've added a link to my homescreen and I start the (web)app from there and things start out ok.
But when I change a page safari shows up and breaks the `look I'm an iphone app`® magic and eats up 25% of my screen.

The intraweb documentation says this is due to the fact that the webadres changes (parameters in the url), so I switched to hidden fields, but to no avail.

**How do I make sure my iphone webapp stays full screen and never goes to safari?**

Comment: You should consider asking this question to TMS.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, and I suggest you ask in the TMS Software newsgroups, with steps to reproduce this behaviour, so they can look into it (which will give you a better chance of solving the issue that asking here, to be honest)...